# getting sql syntax error in my php code

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

i am getting the error sayin "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rs)' at line 2"

here is my code:

```
<div id="main" >
<form name="form1" method="POST" >
<div id="input" align="center">
<table width="700" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Seat Preference</td>
<td>Zone</td>
<td>Meal Preference</td>
<td>Medical Considerations</td>
<td>Dietary Considerations</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>&nbsp;<select name="seat">
<option>Window Seat</option>
<option>Aisle Seat</option>
</select></td>
<td>&nbsp;<select name="zone">
<option>Smoking</option>
<option>Non-Smoking</option>
</select></td>
<td>&nbsp;<select name="meal">
<option>Vegetarian</option>
<option>Non-Vegetarian</option>
</select></td>
<td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="medical"/></td>
<td>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="dietary"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="button" align="center" >
<input type="submit" value="Take Fare and Proceed" name="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
mysql_select_db("cmc");

     if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

$r=mysql_query("select * from reservation where transid=".$_REQUEST["id"].""); $d=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
then query is::

mysql_query("INSERT INTO                         
      manifest(`day`,`month`,`year`,`class`,`sector`,`seat`,`zone`,`meal`,`medical`,`dietary`,`fare`)
VALUES(".$d["day"].",'".$d["month"]."','".$d["year"]."','".$d["class"]."','".$d["sector"]."         ','".$_POST["seat"]."','".$_POST["zone"]."','".$_POST["meal"]."','".$_POST["medical"]."','"    .$_POST["dietary"]."',".$d["fare"].")
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

further code is:

```
 header("Location: print.php");

$dnew=$d["availibilty"]-1;
mysql_query("update reservation set availibility=".$dnew."");
header("Location: print.php");
 }
?>
</div>
```

i am unable to find the error.it is the php code for online reservation for airways

Comment: Not at all familiar with PHP, but could .$dnew."" be replaced with .$dnew

Comment: Code as written is going to be vulnerable to SQL injection -- completely unacceptable in a production application. This is because you are directly sticking user input into your SQL query. You should probably be using `mysqli` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with parameter binding instead.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: What @Dennis says will solve your problem (missing quotes) and what DCoder says is good advice. Consider following it even if it is additional work

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO                         
      manifest(`day`,`month`,`year`,`class`,`sector`,`seat`,`zone`,`meal`,`medical`,`dietary`,`fare`)
VALUES(".$d["day"].",'".$d["month"]."','".$d["year"]."','".$d["class"]."','".$d["sector"]."         ','".$_POST["seat"]."','".$_POST["zone"]."','".$_POST["meal"]."','".$_POST["medical"]."','"    .$_POST["dietary"]."',".$d["fare"].")
    ")
```

Notice the last bit of it looks like this:

```
"',".$d["fare"].") ")
```

But there are no quotes around the value. So you need to change it to:

```
"','".$d["fare"]."') ")
```

Comment: same problem    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rs)' at line 2"

Answer (score 0):

Try below if works for you.

```
$r=mysql_query("select * from reservation where transid='".$_REQUEST['id']."'"); $d=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
```

**Edit:**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO                         
      manifest(`day`,`month`,`year`,`class`,`sector`,`seat`,`zone`,`meal`,`medical`,`dietary`,`fare`)
VALUES('".$d['day']."','".$d['month']."','".$d['year']."','".$d['class']."','".$d['sector']."         ','".$_POST['seat']."','".$_POST['zone']."','".$_POST['meal']."','".$_POST['medical']."','"    .$_POST['dietary']."','".$d['fare']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

This will **Help**: (best practice )
take Query String in to a variable and **echo** the Query to check whether passing the correct Query to `mysql_query()`.

after getting the `Query` printed `run it` in the phpmyadmin (or ur mysql editor).
it will show you what is the error in deep.

Answer (score -1):

It doest seem you are pointing the right code that contains the error since I cannot find "rs)" in your SQL.

Make sure you give us the right SQL request.